# WiX - Launch program from disk?

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I have a working WiX 3.5 installer. After successful install, I know how to get WiX to launch the application that has just been installed.

However, I also want to ship my install CD with a small application that runs from the CD itself - and I'd like this to pop up at the end of the main application install. It's important that the second application runs from the CD.

My first attempt - which launched the primary application at the end of the install - is this:

```
<UI>
    <!--  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />  -->
    <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
             Control="Finish"
             Event="DoAction"
             Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch MyInstalledApp" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />

<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#MyInstalledApp.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

However, I want to change this to launch something like "D:\MyTinyApp.exe" instead. How do I address the source CD using WiX?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot. Assuming the file that you want to execute is in the same location that the MSI file was, you have to go find it first:

```
<Property Id='WixShellExecTarget'>
    <DirectorySearch Id='DirSearch' Path='[SOURCEDIR]' Depth='0'>
        <FileSearch Id='FileSearch' Name='MyFileToRun.exe'/>
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

The [SourceDir] is the key. It should be where the MSI is. You might consider adding a condition as well to do something useful if the file can't be found.

Comment: Thanks for that, and sorry for delay in replying. If I try this code I get "The Property/@Id attribute's value, 'WixShellExecTarget', cannot contain lowercase characters. Since this is a search property, it must also be a public property. This means the Property/@Id value must be completely uppercase." But if I change Id and everything else to uppercase, it gives the same error. Any ideas?